# Holder continuous map preserves $F_\sigma$ sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, holder-spaces

Let $F\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an $F_\sigma$-set and $\Phi:F\to \mathbb{R}^d$ be an $\alpha$-Holder continuous map, that is 
$$|\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)|_\infty \le L|x-y|_\infty^\alpha\; \forall x,y\in F$$ with constant $L$ and exponent $\alpha \in (0,1]$.

Now assume that $J$ is a square of side-length $s<1$ and centre $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then because of the above condition, we have 
$$\Phi(J)=\Phi\Big(\prod_{k=1}^n[c_k-\frac{1}{2}s,c_k+\frac{1}{2}s)\Big)\subset\prod_{k=1}^d[\Phi_k (c)-\frac{L}{2}s^{1/\alpha},\Phi_k(c)+\frac{L}{2}s^{1/\alpha})$$

$|\cdot|_\infty$ is the maximum norm of the vector in the Euclidean space.

I tried showing this by putting $y\in J$, then $|y_k-c_k|\le \frac{1}{2}s$, so $|\Phi(y_k)-\Phi(c_k)|\le |\Phi(y)-\Phi(c)|_\infty \le L|y-c|_\infty^\alpha \le L (\frac{s}{2})^\alpha$. But I don't see how to get the bound $\frac{L}{2}s^{1/\alpha}$ as required. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement seems to be wrong. Take $\Phi(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$.

For $0\le x<y$,
$$\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x} \\
=(y-x)/(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}) \\
\le(y-x)^{1/2}(y+x)^{1/2}/(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}) \\
\le(y-x)^{1/2}(y^{1/2}+x^{1/2})/(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}) \\
=(y-x)^{1/2},$$
similarly for $y<x\le 0$, and for $x<0<y$,
$$|\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{-x}| \\
\le |y-(-x)|^{1/2} \\
\le (|y|+|x|)^{1/2} \\
=(y-x)^{1/2}.$$

So, it is $\tfrac{1}{2}$-Holder with $L=1$. Now, $[-1/4,1/4)$ is mapped onto $[0,1/2]$ which is not a subset of $[-1/8,1/8)$.

Unless I am missing something here.